# Get name of class in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the name of the class that I am currently in. The problem is that I am in a static property. Any idea how I can do this without a reference to `this`?

Comment: Why do you care given that a it is a constant per definition - static properties dont inherit down with the class. so it is always exactly the same return.

Comment: @TomTom: it could be a generic class, so one might want to know what is the value of the generic parameter. The name for different generic parameters could be thought as a different one.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want it, although as TomTom points out, you might not need it:

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a static property, you should be able to make the type name a constant.

If you have a static property in a base class that is inherited, and you are trying to determine the type of the child class that you are in, you can't do this with a static property.  The reason is that the static property is associated with the base class type, not any base class instance.  Use a regular property instead, and use GetType().Name or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The following call should give you the name of the current type...

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
public static class MyClass
{
  public static string FullName
  {
    get { return typeof(MyClass).FullName; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString()`
Which is mentioned over and over again, can be wrong if the Type is generic. It will not figure out the generic type.

```
class Generic<T>
{
    public static string ClassName
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        get 
        {
            return System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you don't use the `NoInlining` directive your code maybe inlined into the callsite which will definitely not yield the results you are after. 
The following code will print ``` Generic``1[T] ```, rather than the particular instantiation it's being called from. 
The solution is fairly obvious just use `MakeGenericMethod` with T to get the right instance.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution is fairly obvious just use MakeGenericMethod with T to get the right instance.

But if you want to know the name of T you cannot use the `MakeGenericMethod`. Another solution is to add a static class with a generic method:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GetName<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
        return string.Format("{0}<{1}>", type.Name, string.Join(",", genericArguments.Select(arg => arg.Name)));
    }
}
```

No change the property `ClassName` to

```
public static string ClassName
{
    get
    {
        return Helper.GetName<Generic<T>>();
    }
}
```

then you will get the correct generic name, for example a call to `Generic<DateTime>.ClassName` will return 
"Generic`1<DateTime>".